# Bad gateway Error with tomcat and apache2

Tags: tomcat, apache2, http-error

I want to run two websites on same system (localhost@8080 and localhost@4040) So I configured dispatcher.any in apache2 so above can be fulfilled. But i am having trouble in fetching data from localhost:8080 render farm. My apache is not able to connect to render farm.
In logs, i am getting

[Thu Apr 26 05:23:55 2012] [E] [4056(1488)] Unable to connect to render rend01 (localhost:8080): Connection refused. 
[Thu Apr 26 05:23:55 2012] [E] [4056(1488)] no valid render found

and my browser is showing 502 error bad gateway.
I don't know what is happening ?

My second server(localhost@4040) is running perfectly fine.
If anybody has any idea about this then please help

Comment: Is there anything listening on port 8080? (The message indicates the opposite). Try `netstat -an | grep LISTEN` if you're on linux

Comment: Thanks MartinK..Actually my tomcat server was hosted on 8080 port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem. It was some syntax mistake and i still could not find the reason.
I am posting answer here because it will definitely help gonna someone else later.

While providing render farms as localhost,
I was using

/hostname: "localhost"

/port: "8080"

Above syntax has mistakes actually. When i replaced "localhost" to 127.0.0.1 it worked.
So correct syntax is

/hostname: 127.0.0.1

/port: "8080"

It fixed the problem. :)